# applying css to specific li class

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a problem with my list.

I want to specify certain colors for each `li` element but can't seem to do it.  It keeps doing it for all of them.

Here's my CSS:

```
#sub-nav-container ul
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 96px;
    left: 594px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#sub-nav-container li 
{
    margin: 0;
}

#sub-nav-container a
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    color: #C1C1C1;
    display: inline;         
}

li.sub-navigation-home-news  
{
    color: #C1C1C1;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0px 90px 0px 0px; 
}
```

Here's the HTML

```html
<div id="sub-nav-container">
    <ul id="sub-navigation-home">
        <li class="sub-navigation-home-news"><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li class="sub-navigation-home-careers"><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        <li class="sub-navigation-home-client"><a href="#">Client Login</a></li>
        <li class="sub-navigation-home-canada"><a href="#">CANADA</a></li>
        <li class="sub-navigation-home-usa"><a href="#">USA</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

That's because of the `<a>` in there and not using the id which you do use a bit further to the top

Change it to:

```
#sub-navigation-home li.sub-navigation-home-news a 
{
 color: #C1C1C1;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 13.5px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 padding: 0px 90px 0px 0px; 
}
```

and it will probably work

Answer (score 1):

The CSS you have applies color #c1c1c1 to all `<a>` elements.

And it also applies color #c1c1c1 to the first `<li>` element.

Perhaps the code you posted is missing something because I don't see any other colors being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Define them more in your css file.  Instead of

```
li.sub-navigation-home-news
```

try

```
#sub-navigation-home li.sub-navigation-home-news
```

Check this for more details:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade

Answer (score 0):

I only see one color being specified (albeit you specify it in two different places.) Either you've omitted some of your style rules, or you simply didn't specify another color.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `color: #C1C1C1;` for all the `a` elements with `#sub-nav-container a`.

Doing it again in `li.sub-navigation-home-news` won't do anything, as it is a parent of the `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified different colors for the li elements but it is being overridden by the specified color in the a within the li. 
Remove  color: #C1C1C1; style from a element and it should work.

Answer (score -2):

I believe it's because #ID styles trump .class styles when computing the final style of an element. Try changing your `li` from `class` to `id`, or you can <strike>try adding !important to your class, like this:</strike>

```
li.sub-navigation-home-news
{
    color: #C1C1C1; !important
```

Comment: Important is evil, try to avoid it as much as possible, it will cause you trouble in the end maintaining your CSS, ending in disaster with !important everywhere.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're right. I didn't realize that. I might have some work to do taking that out of my stylesheets...