# Modifying list title in HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <ul>
        <li>Interests
            <ol>
                <li style="color: orange">Basketball</li>
                <li>Coding</li>
                <li>Weight Lifting</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Jobs
            <ul>
                <li>Tutor</li>
                <li>Salon Associate</li>
            </ul>
        </li>           
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I modify "Interests" (e.g. change its font color) *without* also modifying the ordered list it is a title of?

Comment: Do you mean specifically this case and the first `li` element only, or also other elements in a similar context, such as “Jobs” here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No classes or wrapping required here:

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jgbX7/**

```
li { /* reset all list items */
    color: black; 
}
:not(li) > ul > li { /* all "li" under "ul" which are not under "li" */
    color: red;
}
```

But, of course if you have multiple such lists, then providing a class to the top `ul` would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to give it a class, i.e.

```
<li class="bob">
```

Then:

```
li.bob
{
    color: #C1C1C1;
}
li
{
    color:  black;
}
```

and then refer to that in your style section

Actual color style, just for reference - but you get the idea.

Comment: Also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/6376403/1662973 for more detailed actual sample.

Comment: This would color the inner list, too, via inheritance.

Comment: Jukka - used your answer to improve mine - darn 419'ers.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `Interests` in a `<span>` tag and stylize it.

The part which changes :

```
<li><span style="color: red">Interests</span>
```

The full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <ul>
        <li><span style="color: red">Interests</span>
            <ol>
                <li style="color: orange">Basketball</li>
                <li>Coding</li>
                <li>Weight Lifting</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Jobs
            <ul>
                <li>Tutor</li>
                <li>Salon Associate</li>
            </ul>
        </li>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

fast and easy way is to put a `<span>` around it then you can apply any style

Answer (score 0):

If you select the `li` containing the text and the other list with CSS and apply styles like `color`, this will apply to child elements too if not excluded explicitly.

Just wrap the text in another element:

```
    <li><span>Interests</span>
        <ol>
```

It’s valid and light-weight, and you can apply styles directly.

Also, your `ul` should be closed, and the `title` element must not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can use inline css
suppose

```
<li><span style="color:blue;">Interests</span>
</li>
```